# Gmail deliveredto operator not working for email alias addresses in Google Workspace

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-workspace-for-business

I am using Gmail on Google Workspace and I have multiple aliases setup on my root Gmail account (e.g. *myusername@domain.com*) such as:

- *webmaster@mydomain.com*
- *admin@mydomian.com*
- *privacy@mydomain.com*

Historically, I have been able to search using the deliveredto: operator to find or filter incoming emails by those specific aliases (e.g. *deliveredto:webmaster@mydomain.com*).  This has always worked and the existing filters that have been in place continue to work.

However, today, when I try to execute a search or create a new filter using *deliveredto:alias@mydomain.com* (e.g. *webmaster@mydomain.com*) it now returns EVERY email delivered to my root email account.

If I go into the list of filters I can still see an old filter for one of my aliases based on the deliveredto: operator and if I click edit, it still works. Which is very strange.

TL;DR The old 'has the words' *deliveredto:alias@mydomain.com* filter seems to behave perfectly, but if I try to replicate it with a new filter it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I have a close enough solution that worked for our case.

## Setup

1. We have an account: `shared@businessdomain.com`
2. With an alias: `invoices@businessdomain.com`, and `alerts@businessdomain.com`
3. People send emails to:

   1. `invoices+marker1@businessdomain.com`
   2. `invoices+marker2@businessdomain.com`,
   3. [...]
   4. `invoices+markerN@businessdomain.com`

## Issue

I've also been affected by the `delivered-to` issue that we cannot filter all mails coming to `invoices@businessdomain.com` because all mail from all aliases has been listed in the results.

## Solution

filter:

> Matches: deliveredto:"invoices*businessdomain.com"
>
> Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "invoices/incoming"

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case is to **use quotes** around the email address -- then it works!

[image]

When you create a filter using the quotes, remember to also "update" the filter you previously made, otherwise it won't be saved in the gmail settings.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se].  Stack Exchange with some exceptions requires content to be in English.  Please [edit] your answer accordingly.  Also, the instruction *"When you create a filter using the quotes, remember to also update the filter you previously made, otherwise it won't be saved in the Gmail settings."* requires editing for clarity.  It may be a translation issue but I don't understand the relationship between the "created filter" and the "other filter" you remind to update.